# How to stabilise PHP response times when dealing with multiple simultaneous requests?

Tags: php, performance, apache, optimization

I'm building a PHP application with an API that has be able to respond very rapidly (within 100ms) to all requests, and must be able to handle up to 200 queries per second (requests are in JSON, and responses require a DB lookup + save every time). My code runs easily fast enough (very consistently around 30ms) for single requests, but as soon as it has to respond to multiple requests per second, the response times start jumping all over the place.

I don't think it's a memory problem (PHP's memory limit is set to 128MB and the code's memory usage is only around 3.5MB) or a MySQL problem (the code *before* any DB request is as likely to bottleneck as the bit that interacts with the DB).

Because the timing is so important, I need to get the response times as consistent as possible. So my question is: are there any simple tweaks I can make (to php.ini or Apache) to stabilise PHP's response times when handling multiple simultaneous requests?

Comment: How long does it take to process a request?  That is, once the response is issued, does the PHP code exit immediately?

Comment: What method of dealing with Apache and PHP do you use? Module? CGI? FastCGI? Suexec? Also check the MaxClients directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients).

Comment: @wallyk: I think it should exit almost immediately. I'm using the FuelPHP framework, and my 30ms breaks down into ~14ms for the framework to start / ~16ms for my code (including the DB stuff) to execute (I take that measure just before the response is sent). I guess there might be a few more ms for it to shut down, but I'd *guess* it would be considerably less than the 14ms startup time.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes: I'm using Apache's php5 module.

Comment: To identify the bottleneck you may use xdebug to profile your application, it'll yield a cachegrind file that you can examine to identify bottlenecks

Comment: Also make sure you use APC or some other opcode cache.

Comment: @ChristianKiewiet: I don't think there's a consistent bottleneck in the code, because the bit that slows down is not the same each time. For the purposes of this question, I'm not looking to fix my code, but to fix the environment it runs in.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes: Thanks, these are good suggestions. Could you perhaps put the MaxClients / APC thing in an answer - maybe with a little more detail? I am not familiar with opcode caches, and not clear about how to choose a sensible setting for, eg. MaxClients

Comment: if you need 30ms on an unloaded server to create a response, with 200 queries per second, you need at least six independend _hardware_ threads to get this done. so you really need to cut the time your script needs down to 16% times the number of CPUs available (neglecting other possible bottlenecks) of its current usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the slowest things (easiest to fix) in my experience in a server in terms of bottleneck is going to be your filesystem and hard drives. I think speeding this up will help out in all other areas. 
So you could for example upgrade the hard drive where your httpdocs and database resides. You can put it on an SSD drive for example. Or even make a RAM disk and place all files on it.

Alternatively you can [setup your database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//memory-storage-engine.html) such that it operates off of a Memory storage engine. 
(Related info [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/what-are-reasons-not-to-use-the-memory-storage-engine-in-mysql) too)

Of course for all that you'll need a lot of physical memory. It is also important to note if your web/app hosting you got is shared then your going to have problems with Shared Memory.

[Tune Mysql](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/)

[Tune Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/perf-tuning.html)

[Performance tune PHP](http://phplens.com/lens/php-book/optimizing-debugging-php.php)

Get [Zend Optimizer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads) enabled, or look at [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), or [eAccelerator](http://eaccelerator.net/)

Here's some basic LAMP [tuning](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tune-lamp-1/) [tips](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-tune-lamp-2/) from IBM

Here's [a slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/jignesht/performance-tuning-in-php-presentation) with some good advice as well